# Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found cakephp 3

Tags: php, twitter-oauth, cakephp-3.0

I'm new with cakephp 3. i downloaded the zip file from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth . i placed it in ./vendor/twitteroauth-master
and in my controller i wrote this code :

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Controller\AppController;
require_once(ROOT .DS. 'Vendor' . DS . 'twitteroauth-master' . DS . 'autoload.php');
require_once(ROOT .DS. 'Vendor' . DS . 'twitteroauth-master' . DS . 'src' . DS . 'TwitterOAuth.php');

class TweetsController extends AppController
{
   public function index()
   {
$oauth_access_token = '';
        $oauth_access_token_secret = '';
        $consumer_key = '';
        $consumer_secret = '';
 $tw = new \TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$oauth_access_token,$oauth_access_token_secret);
$ret = $tw->get("statuses/home_timeline", array("count" => 10, "exclude_replies" => true));
$this->set('tweets', $tweets);
}}
```

But i get this error "Class 'TwitterOAuth' not found". Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using composer?

First, add the library to composer.json with the command

```
composer require abraham/twitteroauth
```

This will download the twitteroauth library to your vendor folder and generate autoload files.

Then in your TweetsController.php add `use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;` after `use App\Controller\AppController;`

It should works with these steps.